# Does SharePoint Online have a lookup column threshold?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, lookup-column, threshold

My understanding is SharePoint Foundation, Server, and Server Enterprise have a default lookup column threshold of 8 to listview. I thought this would be an easy thing to locate online, but I haven't been able to find an answer as to whether SharePoint Online shares this quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes It shares this quality as SharePoint online also has lookup column threshold of 8.
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/11914

Comment: Now, It supports 12 lookup per view.

Comment: @RonakPatel: Are you sure? The documentations says so (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?CorrelationId=33c0a687-ab73-47a9-81cf-3953ca45b75a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) but I am still running into issues when a run a query (CSOM) with more than 8 lookup fields (in my case taxanomy fields.)